# SSIS Expression use with SQL Query

Tags: variables, ssis

I've got an ongoing issue that I'm trying to get around. I'm trying to get a file count into a flat file name (that's file count not row count). My plan is to use a lookup table that tells SSIS what number to use, for example :

```
SELECT MAX(FileNumber) AS FileNumber
FROM FileNumber
```

This will return the last number used (as it will be updated at the end of the package), Where I'm struggling is how to get this into the file name variable?? The variable I am using to get the file name is :

```
"L:\\Folder\\Folder\\Folder\\FILE_003_{00}_" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , getdate() )+"-"+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , getdate() ), 2) +"-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , getdate() ), 2) +"_Q1" +".txt"
```

With the {00} being where i need the file count. Can anyone help??

Comment: Have you tried the SQL execute task to get the "FileNumber" and save it to the variable? After that you can use the "FileNumber" into the "FileName" variable. Then you can set the property EvaluateAsExpression to TRUE. then you can write the expression. Hope this helps!

Comment: I haven't no? how would i get the SQL task to save it to a variable?!?

Comment: Create a SQL execute task. Set Connection. Put your query in "SQLStatement". Set ResultSet to "Single row"[since your return only one row]. Go to Result Set page[which is right side]. Click "ADD". Set ResultSet Name = 0 and Select your variable to save the file number. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok i've created the SQL task which gets the file number, created a filenumber variable, how do i get the variable to use the execute SQL task?!?!

Comment: Should file count be the result of your query? ```SELECT MAX(FileNumber)...```?

Comment: In the expression editor use ```@User::filenumber``` (assuming you created the variable in the top level of the package and not within Execute SQL task.

Comment: ok I'm pretty sure I've followed all the steps but its not working!

I've created the SQL Task, set result set to single row, added my sql statement, ive set the result set to Result name 0 and variable name User::FileNumber.

Do i need to update the variable itself to evaluate as expression?!? When i evaluate the expressions it just returns the default value in the expression!??!

Comment: During design time it will appear that the variable does not change, but it actually does during runtime. Don't rely on the variables window to check if it's changed. When it goes back to design time it goes back to the default value. Do you know how to use an expression to dynamically define your filename?

Comment: Yeah pretty sure, so if i run this through it should use the variable in the end filename? ok in knowing that i've just tried executing the sql task and i get "Error: The type of the value being assigned to variable "User:: " differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object."

Comment: Its ok fixed that!!! Thanks Gowdhaman008 and ElectricLlama bit time for helping me sort this!! its now working a treat!!! Thank you !!!!